# Unable to load class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook due to missing dependency org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

Tags: java, groovy, xls

Please assist me, I am unable to read `xls sheet` from `groovy script`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    Unable to load class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook 
    due to missing dependency org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    Unable to load class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook 
    due to missing dependency org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
```

Comment: Also, worthy of note, XLS uses HSSF instead of XSSF, though both are included by default in the Apache POI framework.

Answer (score 6):

I imagine you don't know much about either Java or Groovy.

The runtime is pretty explicit in that you're lacking a dependency (it's telling you it doesn't know the definition for the ListValuedMap class).

If you search the missing dependency name (with its namespace, so in this case `org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap`) you end up finding that it is part of the Apache Commons Collections package that you can download as a jar and reference in your `classpath` before trying again.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi is the link.

Comment: You're right, I should probably have included that in my answer.